# Flutter - Problem with api Json nothing showing on screen

Tags: flutter, api

Im trying to use a Api but my code have something wrong. When i call with ListView.Builder, nothing shows up.

I removed the Count and Query, and im using only the results, i can access the data with this, but do not show nothing.

I already have another Api in my app, which work and im using the same code.

api that im using: https://triad.raelys.com/api/cards/

this is the code:

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<Cards> cardsFromMap(String str) => List<Cards>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Cards.fromMap(x)));

String cardsToMap(List<Cards> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toMap())));

class Cards {
    Cards({
        required this.id,
        required this.name,
        required this.description,
        required this.enhancedDescription,
        required this.tooltip,
        required this.movement,
        required this.seats,
        required this.order,
        required this.orderGroup,
        required this.patch,
        required this.itemId,
        required this.tradeable,
        required this.owned,
        required this.image,
        required this.icon,
        required this.bgm,
        required this.sources,
    });

    int id;
    String name;
    String description;
    String enhancedDescription;
    String tooltip;
    Movement? movement;
    int seats;
    int order;
    int orderGroup;
    String patch;
    int itemId;
    bool tradeable;
    String owned;
    String image;
    String icon;
    String bgm;
    List<Source> sources;

    factory Cards.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Cards(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        description: json["description"],
        enhancedDescription: json["enhanced_description"],
        tooltip: json["tooltip"],
        movement: movementValues.map[json["movement"]],
        seats: json["seats"],
        order: json["order"],
        orderGroup: json["order_group"],
        patch: json["patch"],
        itemId: json["item_id"] == null ? null : json["item_id"],
        tradeable: json["tradeable"],
        owned: json["owned"],
        image: json["image"],
        icon: json["icon"],
        bgm: json["bgm"] == null ? null : json["bgm"],
        sources: List<Source>.from(json["sources"].map((x) => Source.fromMap(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "description": description,
        "enhanced_description": enhancedDescription,
        "tooltip": tooltip,
        "movement": movementValues.reverse[movement],
        "seats": seats,
        "order": order,
        "order_group": orderGroup,
        "patch": patch,
        "item_id": itemId == null ? null : itemId,
        "tradeable": tradeable,
        "owned": owned,
        "image": image,
        "icon": icon,
        "bgm": bgm == null ? null : bgm,
        "sources": List<dynamic>.from(sources.map((x) => x.toMap())),
    };
}

enum Movement { TERRESTRIAL, AIRBORNE }

final movementValues = EnumValues({
    "Airborne": Movement.AIRBORNE,
    "Terrestrial": Movement.TERRESTRIAL
});

class Source {
    Source({
        required this.type,
        required this.text,
        required this.relatedType,
        required this.relatedId,
    });

    String type;
    String text;
    RelatedType? relatedType;
    int relatedId;

    factory Source.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Source(
        type: json["type"],
        text: json["text"],
        relatedType: json["related_type"] == null ? null : relatedTypeValues.map[json["related_type"]],
        relatedId: json["related_id"] == null ? null : json["related_id"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "type": type,
        "text": text,
        "related_type": relatedType == null ? null : relatedTypeValues.reverse[relatedType],
        "related_id": relatedId == null ? null : relatedId,
    };
}

enum RelatedType { ACHIEVEMENT, INSTANCE, QUEST }

final relatedTypeValues = EnumValues({
    "Achievement": RelatedType.ACHIEVEMENT,
    "Instance": RelatedType.INSTANCE,
    "Quest": RelatedType.QUEST
});

class EnumValues<T> {
    Map<String, T> map;
    Map<T, String>? reverseMap;

    EnumValues(this.map);

    Map<T, String> get reverse {
        if (reverseMap == null) {
            reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => new MapEntry(v, k));
        }
        return reverseMap!;
    }
}
```

this is how i call:

```
class RemoteCards {
  Future<List<Cards>> getCards() async {
    var client = http.Client();
    var uri = Uri.parse('https://triad.raelys.com/api/cards/');
    var response = await client.get(uri);
    try {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var json = response.body;
        final result = jsonDecode(json)["results"] as List?;
        return result?.map((e) => Cards.fromMap(e)).toList() ?? [];
      }
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
    }

    return [];
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it return a List of type Cards? Check your result from getCards

Comment: Can you share the code for `ListView.builder`

Comment: im doing this: [link](https://shrib.com/#ArcticLemming7BDWO8P)